# Do you need to pay any type of fees to send tokens?

Tags: tokens

If i made a token and sent it to a few new eos users that has no eos. can they send these tokens back to me with out a fee? in ethereum i need to pay eth to send a token back.

also what stops me from spammimg my tokens to every eos account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the tokens back, the receiver account must have some EOS. This because he needs to stake some of them in order to be able to send a transaction (to call an action) to send the tokens back to you.

There are no fees in EOS but you need to stake resources in order to send transactions. So if you want to spam all the accounts with your tokens you must have enough resources staked. The biggest is the number of the account you want to spam, the biggest must be the value of resources staked.

Comment: what is the minimum the user needs to stake to send the tokens back? this is still problematic for onboarding users then.

Comment: it depends on the complexity of the action that must be executed and the time required. The actual value changes over time and depends on several factor, such as network congestion.